# javascript execute function pressing 'esc' key

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 javascript functions: one of them shows div 'PhotoFull' another hides. 'PhotoFull' is a container Div.. Just black background for another Div inside of it. When the user clicks on black background, PhotoFull dessapears.. but if affects also the Div which is inside of 'PhotoFull' (PhotoFull dessapears while clicking the div which is inside). So For the Div which is inside I use `event.stopPropagation();`
Both functions work, but I also need to hide Div `hideDiv()` when "ESC" key is pressed. `hideDiv()` is executing Div

```
 function showDiv() {
     document.getElementById('PhotoFull').style.display = "inherit";
     event.stopPropagation();
 }

 function hideDiv() {
     var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
     if (event.currentTarget == target) {
         document.getElementById('PhotoFull').style.display = "none";
     }
 }


window.onload=function() {
    document.onkeyup = key_event;
}

function key_event(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) hideDiv();
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div id="PhotoFull" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.75); display:none; z-index: 999;" onclick="hideDiv()">

 <div style="width: 960px; border-radius: 3px; background-color: #ffffff; margin-top: 100px;">
    <img id="one_full" src="numbers/1.jpg" style="max-width: 940px; margin: 10px;" />
 </div>

 </div>
```

Without `event.stopPropagation();` Pressing ESC button executes function `hideDiv()` but with it, nothing happens. Don't know why.
Thanks for attention

Comment: Tryed many things but failed, the code doesn;t work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press Esc key it goes in hideDiv function but the condition goes worng due to below reason.

See Debug trace in picture.
[image]

See **watchExpression** section in debugger. I have added **event** object to watch.
You can see full object description in watchExpression in above image.

You have write below condition in hideDiv function

```
 var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
 if (event.currentTarget == target) {
         document.getElementById('PhotoFull').style.display = "none";
 }
```

in debug trace you can see that **event.currentTarget** is **body**  **target** local variable in the hideDiv function is **document** because you have added your listener for document object canbe seen from your code

```
window.onload=function() {
    document.onkeyup = key_event;
}
```

So the solution is you have to register event listener on proper object which is body.

use below code for window.onload function..

```
window.onload=function() {
    document.body.onkeyup = key_event;
}
```

Comment: Hello! thanks for attention.. I edited my question. I it is possible, please kindly read it once again, I added some additional code

Comment: It is good if you put your HTML. So javascript and HTML can both readable.

Comment: Done! I added html ;)

Comment: I couldn't understand the idea behind logic   

var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
     if (event.currentTarget == target) {

Comment: It goes in hideDiv when you press Esc, but condition goes wrong.

Comment: Added solution please check.

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onkeypress = keypress;

function keypress(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 27) {
    alert("Hidding div *magic runing...*");  
  }
}
```

You should consider using `onkeypress` event to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
            document.onkeydown=function(e){
                if(e.which == 27) {
                 hidediv();
                 return false;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`window.onkeydown = keypress;
function keypress(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 27) {
    alert("triggered")
  }
}
```

Comment: try this. onkeypress is depricted

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).